# local static ip on debian get a dynamic IP when network goes down even if I change the interfaces file

Tags: debian-wheezy, static-ip

I have a local MYSQL server on Debian 7 x64(wheezy) that I use for centralized local development and testing with almost 10 computers.

I need constantly to access by his IP address. Its on DHCP and can be a headache to change the ip address of the server every time the IP changes. The problem is that every time I change the `/etc/network/interfaces` with this conf when the computer restarts its changes to DHCP again even if the `interfaces` file is modified.

`auto lo
iface lo inet loopback`

`auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.0.254
    network 10.0.0.0
    broadcast 10.0.0.255`

Comment: Is NetworkManager running?